# I receive a CommunicationException on any port other than 443

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have a standard n-tier application (.Net 4.7.2) with a console server and a WinForms application both running on the same machine. The client and server communicate via WCF.

I get a `CommunicationException` on the client when I attempt to communicate with the server if I use any port other than 443 in my address binding.  not specifying a port or explicitly specifying 443 works without an issue.

The error message is;

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
> `https://localhost:44333/SecurityTokenService/issue/wstrust/mixed/anonymous`.
> This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
> configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also
> be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and
> the server.

here is my client binding for reference

```
<endpoint 
    address="https://localhost:44333/SecurityTokenService/issue/wstrust/mixed/anonymous"
    binding="customBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="MySecurityTokenEndpointBinding" 
    contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustChannelContract" 
    name="SecretTokenAuthenticationEndPoint" />
```

UPDATE: I have continued to investigate the issue myself and enabled WCF tracing.  I can see from the trace logs the warning 'The Security Protocol cannot secure the outgoing message'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the correct way to call the wcf service, such as adding service reference, channel factory, etc. After reading your question, I think it is very likely as the error message says: 'This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.'

You can use the following code to specify the TLS version:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

TLS1.3 is the latest TLS standard protocol, which is faster and has higher security.
Here is the reference: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: Thanks for your comment;  I am confident the bindings are correct because as I stated in the question, this error only occurs when my service is exposed on a port other than 443.  if the service is exposed on 443 then there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to bind the SSL certificate to the IP Address and Port that my service was being exposed on. I used the following command from a command prompt;

netsh http add sslcert ipport={ipAddress}:{port} certhash={CertificateThumbprint} appid={appId}

Some points to note

1. If the above command fails; ensure you have the private key imported and not just the public certificate
2. I don't know if the appId is an arbitrary Guid; I used the Guid from my application shell project (a console application); It's the Guid that exposes your application to 'com'

Hopefully, this helps somebody in the future